# Single row DataFrame causing "Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function returning a dictionary with two DataFrames. One of them has multiple rows with no issues. The second will typically come back with a single row. When trying to remove columns from it or even re-creating a second DataFrame and limiting the columns such as this...

```
 analysis['race'] = pd.DataFrame(output['race'], columns=rfactors)
```

...where `rfactors` is a list of the columns. However, I get the following error...

```
 Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

If I don't try and "restrict" the columns, it works fine. Here is the "print" from the returned DataFrame for reference..

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
 Data columns (total 62 columns):
 race_id                 1  non-null values
 track_code              1  non-null values
 race_date               1  non-null values
 race_number             1  non-null values
 ...
 raceshape               1  non-null values
 dtypes: float64(8), int64(25), object(29)
```

My objective here is to clean-up the DataFrame and remove fields no longer needed for eventual insertion into a database. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Turns-out, the reason for the error, as far as I can tell, was a few duplicate columns in the DataFrame. When I removed those, the error subsided.